# In computational creativity, how do you measure how creative something is?

Tags: computability

In computational creativity, how do you measure how creative something is?

Let's say you have to compare a piece of music written by Bach and then compare it to Chopin, how would you evaluate how creative they are and compare them both by giving them scores? How would the model work, are there existing models, and how does computational creativity define creativity in the first place?

Comment: Please show what research about the topic you have done. What about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_creativity#Defining_creativity_in_computational_terms and references? There seem to be a lot of material about the topic; did you really find zero clues?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Creativity is subjective.  There is no such metric.

Comment: Everything is subjective, every model is subjective.

Comment: That's some heavy philosophical debate right here, but how about we get back to computer science?

Comment: If a computer AI that was programmed to be more creative takes less time to create X rather than Y, how can you say there can't be any such metric. Sounds far-fetched and ridiculous to me.

Comment: @Sayaman, I'm sharing the best answer I have to the question you asked.  I hope you'll find someone else who is able to offer you an answer that you find more helpful.

Comment: https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/frai.2020.00014/full

Comment: https://mcreativeai.github.io/eunsukang_mCAI_Intro.pdf